# In extjs4 how to show compulsory fields

Tags: extjs

i am working in extjs4, I have two fields as=

```
items :[{                       
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    maxLength: 255,
                    emptyText: 'task1'
                },{
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    scope: me,
                    listeners: {
                        change: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {

                        }
                    }
```

With this I have add button. On clicking on add button, I have to show both of the above fields as mandatory fields in red border showing compulsory field. But its showing only first one in red border, not both. So what i need to include in code so that both fields will get highlighted in red when submitted as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Hello For that you should submit your Form or apply each field Invalid.

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Test Button',
    handler: function() {

        // this.up('form').getForm().submit();

        // or

        this.up('form').getForm().findField('email').markInvalid('Email');
        this.up('form').getForm().findField('password').markInvalid('Password');

    }
}]
```

In above Code Either you can submit your form will display all fields of that form in Invalid state.

Or

You can add add manual Invalid state to each field as given in above example.

Comment: Thanx for reply sir..But though allowblank:false is included, why not that working?

Comment: If you have choosen `allowBlank:false` and click on submit button it should be working. Have you added your custom error class to change color or border? Can you check that after click on submit button will apply any `Invalid Class` to that Component?